# It is possible to use two domains for one drupal installation (and how)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I have my drupal site

```
http://www.example.com
```

a whole and complete website. For a various of (tedious, believe me) reasons, i had to build another website on the same drupal installation using the *SAME* database. This second website is made of pages having url

```
http://www.example.com/example2/something_else.html
```

Now, i bought a domain for the second website, too. I can redirect from this domain, let's say the second domain to be

```
 http://www.example2.com
```

, to the main page of my second website

```
 http://www.example.com/example2/index.html
```

but the url displayed on pages, in this way, is

```
 http://www.example.com/example2/something_else.html
```

instead of

```
 http://www.example2.com/something_else.html
```

I'm thinking i need to use Apache Virtual Hosts or Rewrite Rules in .htaccess but i don't really know how to do or if it is possible. Can you hel me?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few settings that are important. In the settings.php add a switch depending on domain (I guess you have this already to select a different database for each domain) but in here make sure the $base_url is set for both domains.

Flush the caches and that should be close

Comment: I can't test this approach now, but i'm pretty sure it would work. Nice idea

Comment: Can't do it for i am using the same database for the two website an so i have only one setting.php.